# Renaming prefixes of table field's names within phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

Is there a more dynamic way to rename all prefixes of fields in a table of a database within phpmyadmin, rather than manually typing to replace the name for each  fields? I have aboutnumber of table fields to change prefixes on..

Comment: if you update that what is existing results and what result you want, then it will be easy to help you...

Comment: Now my table's fields have the prefix  ' cus_ ' so i need to remove this prefix from fields,actually this is my requirement

Comment: I think no, because there is not such possibility with the MySQL itself. You would need to use something like `ALTER TABLE xxx ALTER COLUMN *...` (or `...CHANGE COLUMN`), but you can't use `*` in `ALTER COLUMN` or add any `WHERE` in `ALTER TABLE` [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)